# <Buttons> in VS Code getting indented further when being saved

Tags: visual-studio-code

My buttons keep being indented away and became slanted every time it's saved. I turned off all of my extensions beside Live Server and it is still happening. Can anyone help me?

**This is what's happening:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ7xi.png

**What's supposed to happen:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CShef.png

Comment: Welcome to SO, are you sure `<button"></button>` is correct? Seems to me there is a " too much that makes VSC think the following characters are part of a string. Try `<button></button>`.